# ZabbixApi - symfony5 throwing $authToken error

Tags: php, symfony, zabbix, php-8, zabbix-api

I'm having some problems with zabbixAPI on symfony5(using confirm-it-solutions/php-zabbix-api lib with php8) and im recieving this error: Warning: **Undefined property: ZabbixApi\ZabbixApi::$authToken** and to be honest i have no idea whats wrong, after trying using like getHosts or almost big part of them im getting this error. After using getApiUrl im getting data.

```
class ZabbixController
{
/**
* @Route (path="zabbix",name="zabbix_worker")
* @return Response
*/
    function zabbixGraph(): Response
    {
    $zabbixUrl = 'url';
    $zabbixUser = 'user';
    $zabbixPassword = 'passwd';
    $zabbixData = [$zabbixUrl,$zabbixUser, $zabbixPassword];

    try {
    $api = new ZabbixApi($zabbixData);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    $GetGraphId = $api->graphGet(array(
    'output' => 'extend',
    'filter' => array('host' =>'abros'),
    'search' => array('name' => 'Network traffic on')
    ));
    echo($GetGraphId);
    return new Response($GetGraphId);
}}
```

[here's screen of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSLiC.png)
Huge thanks for any kind of help/clue/anything

Comment: In the documentation ZabbixApi does not take an array but arguments new try ZabbixApi(...$zabbixData) instead of your current construct

Comment: after trying your method im getting this error: array_key_exists(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, stdClass given

Comment: Where do you have this error ?

Comment: this line:   $api = new ZabbixApi(...$zabbixData);